# PHP strings: how to replace non-standard characters?

Tags: php, preg-replace

How can I replace part of a string, when that part and the replacement both include special characters? e.g.

```
$text = "|123|12|12|";
$text = preg_replace("|0|","|12|",$text, 1);
echo($text);
```

Desired output: "|123|0|12|"

The special characters don't matter as long as they are preserved. E.g.

```
$text = "#123#12#12#";
$text = preg_replace("#0#","#12#",$text, 1);
echo($text);
```

Desired output: "#123#0#12#"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace` if you don't need regexp. It's more efficient and avoids the need to escape anything.

If you need to use `preg_replace` (for instance to take advantage of the fact that you can specify a limit for the number of replacements, unlike with `str_replace`), use [`preg_quote`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to escape the special characters.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I only replace the first occurrence? str_replace seems to want to change everything.

Comment: @Chris: So does `preg_replace`, actually.

Answer (score 1):

The | acts as the marker for the start of the regex. You're quite close really:

```
$text = "|123|12|12|";
$text = preg_replace("/|0|/","|12|",$text, 1);
echo($text);
```

Here I used / as the start and end-markers. You can use any character. / is quite common.

Note that str_replace would also suffice here

Comment: Thanks. I tried that in http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and it came up with /|12|/|123|12|12|

Comment: Even after fixing the backwards pattern and replacement strings, this will result in something like |12|||12|1|12|2|12|3|12|||12|...  The | means "or", so the pattern will match the empty string between each char unless the |s are escaped.

Comment: Sorry for being dense, but it doesn't work for me. e.g. $text = "|123|12|12|";
$text = preg_replace("\|0\|","\|12\|",$text, 1);
echo($text); the output is |123|12|12| - how do I escape these characters?

Comment: @Chris: Your pattern needs chars before and after it.  Evert chose `/` (which is the most common).  Your pattern doesn't have those.  But with that fixed, you're trying to find `|0|` (which doesn't exist in the string).  Reverse the `|0|` and `|12|`, and you're a tiny bit closer (but you'll still have problems with the last `|12|` getting replaced as well).

Comment: Thanks. I'm more confused than ever - I think I'll just send the input to the local machine, process it in javascript and send it back. PHP seems like a black art.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern needs escapement,because the '|' is a special char in reg rules.
Use '\' to escape your char, and then use '/' as the delimiter of your pattern.
Try this. :)

```
$text = "|123|12|12|";
$text = preg_replace("/\|12\|/","|0|",$text, 1);
echo($text);
```

EDIT:
BTY, I guess you want to replace the first '|12|' with '|0|', but your code makes me puzzled.
The function preg_replace's statement is as below:

> mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
>
> > Searches subject for matches to pattern and replaces them with replacement.

Maybe you had put the parameters in wrong places.
See more about preg_replace: http://cn.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php